# Python: confluent_kafka does not receive ANY Msg

Tags: confluent-kafka-python

I have a [Strimzi](https://strimzi.io/) Kafka setup and try to connect to it with the following code:

```
from confluent_kafka import Consumer
c = Consumer({
    "bootstrap.servers": "HOST:PORT",
    'group.id':'GR',
    'auto.offset.reset': 'earliest',
    'enable.auto.commit': False,
    'security.protocol': 'SASL_SSL',
    'sasl.mechanisms': 'SCRAM-SHA-512',
    'sasl.username': 'username',
    'sasl.password': 'password',
    'debug':'all'
})

c.subscribe(['topic'])

print("start...")
while True:
    msg = c.poll(1.0)

    if msg is None:
        continue
    if msg.error():
        print("Consumer error: {}".format(msg.error()))
        continue

    print('Received message: {}'.format(msg.value().decode('utf-8')))

c.close()
```

With that code I do not receive ANY message.

With the `kafka-python` library **I receive all messages**:

```
consumer = KafkaConsumer('topic',
                     group_id='GR',
                     bootstrap_servers='HOST:PORT',
                     enable_auto_commit=False,
                      auto_offset_reset='earliest',
                     value_deserializer=lambda x: x.decode('utf-8'),
                     security_protocol='SASL_SSL',
                     sasl_mechanism='SCRAM-SHA-512',
                     sasl_plain_username='username',
                     sasl_plain_password='password')

for message in consumer:
    print(message)
```

Is `confluent_kafka` not supporting Strimzi? What is wrong with my code?